# Match all newline characters using stringr

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a text that has random newline characters `\n`. I want to extract part of that text after a certain phrase.

```
text <- "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \nconsectetur adipiscing elit, \nsed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. \nUt enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. \nDuis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse \ncillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. \nExcepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
```

I want to extract text from phrase `Duis` till the end. My attempts are below

```
str_extract(text, "(Duis.+)")
[1] "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse "

str_extract(text, "(Duis.+)(\\s.*)")
[1] "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse \ncillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. "
```

My desired output

```
"Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse \ncillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. \nExcepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
```

How can I achieve the target without replacing `\n` from the original text?

Comment: How do you know where the match should stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[\\s\\S]` to match everything including new lines.

```
stringr::str_extract(text, 'Duis[\\s\\S]*')
[1] "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse \ncillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. \nExcepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
```

Answer (score 0):

you can keep the original text as what it's and create a variable hold this text after changes which means that you can do the following

```
var oldText = "myText";
var newText = oldText.split("\n");
console.log(newText)
```

- this will return every part after \n of you text inside array and you can select the part you want from the array index